# How to add lwip library in Xilinx SDK for linux Plattform

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded-linux, xilinx, petalinux

Well, my question is to ask how can i add the lwip library to the tool Xilinx SDK to use it in Embedded linux environment. I tried a lot but always debug problems are there. I added this library for example lwip-2.0.2 from the link http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/lwip/

currently i have a Zybo board based on Zynq 7010 and i want to develop an application which can use the protocol TCP/IP.

I looked around a lot but i am not getting the right way to be able to use the lwip stack.

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWIP is generally used for bare metal firmware [refer this link](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/21430395/Zynq-7000+AP+SoC+Performance+Gigabit+Ethernet+achieving+the+best+performance#Zynq-7000APSoCPerformance%E2%80%93GigabitEthernetachievingthebestperformance-BaremetallwIPTCP/IPstack)

When Zynq is running petalinux, you can directly use Linux POSIX TCP/IP stack.
[E.g TCP Server/Client Linux code](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/?utm_source=feedburner)

You can select **Linux OS** in **OS Platform** and develop Linux application in Xilinx SDK. [Linux application using SDK](https://www.xilinx.com/video/hardware/how-to-create-linux-applications.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am trying your answer. But the connection between the PC and the board can not be established yet. As it works, i will let you know?

Comment: @A.S. Sure. Could you tell what exactly is happening?

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Well the Ethernet was not reachable and there should be a work around in Petalinux. Now i can not ping the board on Linux host but on Windows host it works :)

Comment: now it works also on linux host. The Ethernet must be configured :)